# Inverse log-convexity of Lp-norms

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help.

The log-convexity of Lp-norms states like:

$\|u\|_{L_{p_{\theta}}}\leq \|u\|_{L_{p_0}}^{1-\theta}\|u\|_{L_{p_1}}^{\theta}$

where $\frac{1}{p_{\theta}}=\frac{1-\theta}{p_0}+\frac{\theta}{p_1}$.

My question is: do we have the inverse inequality, namely:

$\|u\|_{L_{p_{\theta}}}\geq C \|u\|_{L_{p_0}}^{1-\theta}\|u\|_{L_{p_1}}^{\theta}$

for some constant $C$?

If this is not true, what if we raise the index a little bit, say replace $p_{\theta}$ with some bigger $p$?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't. To see this (I'll use different numbers) let
$$ \frac{1}{r} = \frac{\theta}{p}+\frac{1-\theta}{q}$$ where $ p < r < q$ and $0<\theta<1$ then we have the inequality
$$
\| f\|_r \leq \| f\|_p^{\theta} \|f\|_q^{1-\theta}
$$
Now we know that the function $f(x) = x^{-a}$ has finite integral on $[0, 1]$ if $a<1$, Using this we can construct a function $$g(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{q+\epsilon}}$$ then $|g(x)|^r$ is always integrable on $[0,1]$ so $\|g(x)\|_r$ is always finite, but as $\epsilon \to 0$ the integral $\int_0^1 |g(x)|^q d\mu$ grows to infinity. Surely we cannot bound it by a constant $C$ that works for all $\epsilon$.